# Apagar conteúdo incluindo pastas

Tags: cmd

Estou tentando apagar o conteúdo de uma pasta mas estou com o seguinte problema:

- Usando o comando `del` ele apaga só arquivos e as pastas ficam (tem que apagar as pastas também).
- Usando o comando `rd` ele apaga além do conteúdo todo, apaga a pasta raiz também.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Tente `rd /s /q`

Comment: @acklay tentei mas ele apaga a raiz também.

Comment: Se você colocar assim: `rd /s /q C:\path\to\directory\* ` não vai?!

Comment: @acklay não dá, acontece até uma mensagem de erro falando que está incorreto o label se colocar o * .

Comment: Veja minha resposta, testei aqui e funcionou. Pode usar tb o `Erase`.

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui pra vê se ajudar: https://ss64.com/nt/del.html

Comment: Muito Bom! Deleta as sub-pastas e arquivos, mas mantem a RAIZ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quiser manter o diretório raiz por algum motivo e deseja realmente esvaziá-lo, então você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
del /q caminho_destino\*
for /d %x in (caminho_destino\*) do @rd /s /q "%x"
```

O primeiro comando remove todos os arquivos do diretório e, em seguida, o segundo remove recursivamente todos os diretórios aninhados, e mantém o diretório de nível raiz como está (exceto pelo seu conteúdo que foi apagado). Vale ressaltar que **caminho_destino** é o caminho do diretório que deseja esvaziar.

Observe que dentro de um arquivo .bat você precisa dobrar o `%` no loop `for`:

```
del /q caminho_destino\*
for /d %%x in (caminho_destino\*) do @rd /s /q "%%x"
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.

Comment: Disponha, fico feliz que tenha resolvido.

Comment: Muito bom, acabei tendo a mesma ideia só que só vi sua postagem depois de editada minha resposta. Acontece. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Editada, Script:
>
> A primeira versão não exclui as subpastas, entao tente o script abaixo:

```
del /q "C:\Teste\*.*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Teste\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

---

```
mkdir teste
cd \teste
mkdir files
cd files
echo $null >> file.txt
cd \
del /S teste\*.*
```

Comment: Tentei, ele apaga só os arquivos, a pasta continua.

Comment: A pasta raiz? vc queria deleta-la tb?

Comment: Seu script não funciona, observe... Mas não quero apagar a raiz, só o conteúdo dela.

Comment: Ok, verifique q nao funcionou mesmo, vou editar para uma nova versao

Comment: Não testei pq estou no linux, mas assim que liberar uma mq windows aqui vou testar.